# Get iOS device token only after toggle in notification settings

Tags: ios, notifications

We have an app in the Apple app store which already uses local notifications.

Within a new release we also added remote notifications. During development and testing everything worked fine. We were able to get a device token and send push notifications to that device.

After submitting the app to the Apple app store and updating the existing app (via auto-update) after being reviewed we were not able to get a device token any more.

If we go to settings > notifications and turn notifications off an on again and restart our app we are able to get a device token. But this is not satisfying and we can not tell our users to do that.

It seems like the app uses the old notifications settings. Is this a known bug or are there any workarounds?

Thanks in advance.